# Optional Email Verification in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I make the email verification optional in Laravel? I have a routes that can be accessed as guest. However, I want all authenticated user to be email verified whenever they access any part of the website including those pages that can be access as guest.

If I'm going to add `middleware('verified')` on all routes, guest needs to login to access those public pages.

Example:

Route `/` or `/posts/1` can be access as a guest. However, if the user is logged in, I want them to be email verified first to access it.

Comment: If you assign the `verified` middleware in your controller constructor, you could wrap it in a conditional which checks if the user is authenticated.

Comment: Or much better is to wrap the routes into a Route Group to group the routes that needs to an email verification and for guests.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a global middleware to filter it. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#global-middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EnsureEmailIsVerified` (`verified`) middleware checks to see if the User is authenticated which is why it won't work for guest users.

You could create a new middleware class called something like `EnsureEmailIsVerifiedUnlessGuest` (or whatever you want):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null)
{
    if ( $request->user() &&
        ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
        ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
        return $request->expectsJson()
                ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
                : Redirect::guest(URL::route($redirectToRoute ?: 'verification.notice'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Then add it to the `$routeMiddleware` array in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:

```
'verified-or-guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerifiedUnlessGuest::class,
```

Then you can use it with your routes with

```
->middleware('verified-or-guest')
```